# Valgrind reporting memory leak in RocksDB

Tags: profiling, valgrind, rocksdb

I am trying to profile the performance of RocksDB using Callgrind / KCacheGrind on a mac. I am running the command `valgrind --tool=callgrind ./simple_example` on one of the example programs that comes with RocksDB in the examples folder. I seem to be getting a memory leak,  though, which prevents me from being able to do the performance profiling that I ultimately want to do.

```
==54628== Callgrind, a call-graph generating cache profiler
==54628== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Josef Weidendorfer et al.
==54628== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==54628== Command: ./simple_example
==54628== 
==54628== For interactive control, run 'callgrind_control -h'.
==54628== 
==54628== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==54628==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==54628==    at 0x1016D25BA: _pthread_body (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==54628==    by 0x1016D250C: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==54628==    by 0x1016D1BF8: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==54628==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==54628==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==54628==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==54628==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==54628==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
--54628:0:schedule VG_(sema_down): read returned -4
==54628== 
==54628== Events    : Ir
==54628== Collected : 14961779
==54628== 
==54628== I   refs:      14,961,779
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: callgrind does not detect memory leak, it is memcheck that detects them. Memcheck also would not stop for a memory leak. The above crash is either due to a real problem in simple_program (unlikely ?) or (more likely) a problem in valgrind on Mac (valgrind is less tested on Mac, and might have some more problems on newer MacOS versions). There are several bugs opened for (better) support of macOS 10.12/13/14/15). See e.g. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=399584

Comment: Thanks much! It shouldn't be a problem with the client program as I haven't changed anything in the RocksDB original example problem. Your suggestion of a compatibility problem with MacOS makes sense though. So do you think I can still use the output file from callgrind despite this problem?

Comment: It is not clear to me that the callgrind output file contains something relevant enough for your program.  It depends at what time it crashes.  If it crashes when your program is terminating, then the callgrind file will show relevant results.  But it it crashes before your program did anything significant, it will all be quite useless.